# Spring Data JPA - two IN clause and one OR - QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My Spring data query is:

```
@Query("FROM NewsFeed nf where dealRoom.id =:dealRoomId and (fileFolder IN :folders or file in :files)")
Page<NewsFeed> findByFolder(@Param("dealRoomId") final String dealRoomId, @Param("files") final List<File> files, @Param("folders") final List<FileFolder> folders, final Pageable pageable);
```

But i take:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [select count(nf) FROM NewsFeed nf where dealRoom.id =:dealRoomId and (fileFolder IN (:folders_0_, :folders_1_, :folders_2_, :folders_3_, :folders_4_, :folders_5_, :folders_6_, :folders_7_, :folders_8_, :folders_9_) or file in :files_0_, :files_1_, :files_2_, :files_3_, :files_4_, :files_5_, :files_6_, :files_7_, :files_8_, :files_9_, :files_10_, :files_11_)]
```

Does anyone knows why i take QuerySyntaxException?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with second `IN` clause which is generating faulty sql (values are not surrounded with parentheses):

```
file in :files_0_, :files_1_, :files_2_
```

This was a recognized bug in hibernate, and seems to be fixed for 5.0.7 [HHH-9630](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9630)